# How to I set the Connection : Keep-Alive header to Close in the JsonServiceClient?

Tags: servicestack

On occasion (not consistently), I'm receiving a "***The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server***" exception thrown by an instance of the JsonServiceClient.  I want to set the Http Connection Header to Close.

When I attempt ***client.Headers["Connection"] = "Close";*** "***I get a The 'Connection' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method.\r\nParameter name: name***" exception.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the HTTP Request Connection header using a Request Filter, e.g:

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient {
    RequestFilter = req => req.Connection = "Close"
};
```

Comment: I'm trying:             var client = new JsonServiceClient
            {
                RequestFilter = req => req.Connection = "Close"
            };

            client.BaseUri = "http://echo.jsontest.com/"

            var response = client.Get<string>("message");  _But getting an "Keep-Alive and Close may not be set using this property.
Parameter name: value" exception._

Comment: AFAIK There's no other API that you can use to set this, but realistically you shouldn't need to touch this. I'm assuming there's another reason why the server is prematurely terminating connections, can't tell from here tho.

Answer (score 0):

you can Just use this to close the connection
{Connection: close};